# How to get selected item from ListView by using Contains function

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, fastreport

There are several elements in the `ListView`. When I click one of them, I can do some operations like print, preview, labeling, etc.
So, in the codebehind I want to use the `Contains` function to get specific keywords.

```
Dim FREPORT as Report 
If purch_tab.Selected Then
    Dim name As String = ""
    For a = 0 To purch_listview1.Items.Count - 1
        name = purch_listview1.FocusedItem.Text.Contains("Order")
        If name = "Siparişi" Then
            TMODE = 1
            FREPORT.SetParameterValue("TMODE", TMODE)
        ElseIf name = "Dispatch" Then
            TMODE = 2
            FREPORT.SetParameterValue("TMODE", TMODE)
        ElseIf name = "Invoice" Then
            TMODE = 3
            FREPORT.SetParameterValue("TMODE", TMODE)
        End If
    Next
End If
```

How can I access the index of `ListView` elements using `Contains` or any other function?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Actually, solution was really simple. It may help someone.

```
Dim FREPORT as Report        
If purch_tab.Selected Then
                            Dim namee As ListViewItem = purch_listview1.SelectedItems(0)
                            If namee.Text.Contains("Order") Then
                                TMODE = 1
                                FREPORT.SetParameterValue("TMODE", TMODE)
                            End If
                            If namee.Text.Contains("Dispatch") Then
                                TMODE = 2
                                FREPORT.SetParameterValue("TMODE", TMODE)
                            End If
                            If namee.Text.Contains("Invoice") Then
                                TMODE = 3
                                FREPORT.SetParameterValue("TMODE", TMODE)
                            End If
                        End If
```